# jQuery is JS library. what the term library means?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't understand the meaning of the word library -
regarding to jQuery: will it be right to say that "library" is a huge file with many plug ins that are ready to use?

Comment: It's a term that has been in use for describing software for 50 years or more. Your interpretation is as good as any; the terminology is not very rigorous.

Comment: Google directs you to a wiki page with a decent answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_library

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library is something that extends a base langage. So in this definition jQuery is a library

Answer (score 1):

> jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML
>   document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions
>   for rapid web development. jQuery is designed to change the way that
>   you write JavaScript.

All this means is that jQuery itself does not do anything. A library is "a collection of resources used to develop software". jQuery allows you to write cross-browser JavaScript a heck of a lot easier than it would be without it.

Answer (score 0):

A small(not huge!!!) file (32K only)... With many many functions and features.

> Libraries contain code and data that provide services to independent programs. This encourages the sharing and changing of code and data in a modular fashion, and eases the distribution of the code and data.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29)